# Setting the Permission from one particular App to the another in Android

Tags: android, permissions, set

I have been working on an Application where I need to get the Permission set that is being set by the another individual application without getting rooted.

Is there any clue out for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I have seen that is possible, when you control both apps is the "sharedUserId"

used in the manifest file: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html